# Regex to extract string if there is or not a specific word

Tags: regex

Hi I'm a regex noob and I'd like to make a regex in order to extract the penultimate string from the URL if the word "**xxxx**" is contained or the last string if the word "**xxxx**" is not contained.

For example, I could have 2 scenarios:

- www.hello.com/aaaa/1adf0023efae456
- www.hello.com/aaaa/1adf0023efae456/**xxxx**

In both cases I want to extract the string 1adf0023efae456.

I've tried something like `(?=(\w*xxxx\w*)\/.*\/(.*?)\/|[^\/]+$)` but doesn't work properly.

Comment: How come `1adf0023efae456` in the first case is penultimate?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can match the forward slash before the digits, then match  digits and assert what follows is either xxxx or the end of the string.

```
\d+(?=/xxxx|$)
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/6U9caz/1)

If there should be a `/` before matching the digits, you could use a capturing group and get the value from group 1

```
/(\d+)(?=/xxxx|$)
```

- `/` Match `/`
- `(\d+)` Capture group 1, match 1+ digits
- `(?=/xxxx|$)` Positive lookahead, assert what is on the right is either xxxx or end of string

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/5CczT2/1)

**Edit**

If there could possibly also be alphanumeric characters instead of digits, you could use a character class `[a-z0-9]+` with an optional non capturing group.

```
/([a-z0-9]+)(?:/xxxx)?$
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/2NlIGJ/1)

To match any char except a whitespace char or a forward slash, use `[^\s/]+`

---

Using lookarounds, you could assert a `/` on the left, match 1+ alphanumerics and assert what is at the right is either `/xxxx` or the end of the string which did not end with `/xxxx`

```
(?<=/)[a-z0-9]+(?=/xxxx$|$(?<!/xxxx))
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/gGcAC7/1)

Comment: Actually, I don't know if that string will be composed only with digit

Comment: @GiuseppeCapuano Do you mean like this? `/([^/\r\n]+)(?:/xxxx)?$` https://regex101.com/r/cTzhzy/1 or `/(\w+)(?:/xxxx)?$`

Comment: i mean that maybe, in the future the string will be composed with alphanumeric characters. Something like 
www.hello.com/aaaa/1adf0023efae456
www.hello.com/aaaa/1adf0023efae456/xxxx

Comment: @Beppe94 This pattern would work for those cases right? https://regex101.com/r/cTzhzy/1

Comment: I've tested, but actually now in the case of www.hello.com/aaaa/1adf0023efae456/xxxx it gets /1adf0023efae456/xxxx and i only want the string 1adf0023efae456

Comment: @Beppe94 The value is in the first capturing group, which is highlighted in green on the regex101 link. What is the tool or programming language?

Comment: it is an embedded tools in CA API Gateway but, in the www.hello.com/aaaa/1adf0023efae456/xxxx it matches /1adf0023efae456/xxxx

Comment: @Beppe94 If a lookbehind is supported, try `(?<=/)[a-z0-9]+(?=/xxxx$|$(?<!/xxxx))` https://regex101.com/r/gGcAC7/1

Answer (score 0):

You could avoid Regex:

```
string[] strings =
{
    "www.hello.com/aaaa/1adf0023efae456",
    "www.hello.com/aaaa/1adf0023efae456/xxxx"
};
var x = strings.Select(s => s.Split('/'))
        .Select(arr => new { upper = arr.GetUpperBound(0), arr })
        .Select(z => z.arr[z.upper] == "xxxx" ? z.arr[z.upper - 1] : z.arr[z.upper]);
```